# Postgres find unique values ​in json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Postgresql and have a table, with id, sender::jsonb and date, as follows:

```
id |                                      sender                                        | last login date                 
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------
  1 | {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-10 14:49:36.234504 +00:00   
  2 | {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-09 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  3 | {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-11 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  4 | {"firstName": "Nickolai","lastName": "Nickov",       "middleName": "Nikovich", }  | 2021-04-30 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  5 | {"firstName": "Nickolai","lastName": "Nickov",       "middleName": "Nikovich", }  | 2021-04-29 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  6 | {"firstName": "Vladimir","lastName": "Vladimirovich","middleName": "Putout", }    | 2021-04-15 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  7 | {"firstName": "Petr",    "lastName": "Petrov",       "middleName": "Petrovich", } | 2021-04-10 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  8 | {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-01 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  9 | {"firstName": "Ignat",   "lastName": "Ignatov",      "middleName": "Ignatovich", }| 2021-04-06 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  10| {"firstName": "Vladimir","lastName": "Vladimirovich","middleName": "Putout", }    | 2021-04-17 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  11| {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-12 14:49:36.234504 +00:00
```

p.s.There may be other information in the "sender" column, but the search for uniqueness is only necessary by "firstName", "lastName", "midddleName"

It is necessary to return a result consisting of unique names and with the latest date. In particular, I want to get the result:

```
id |                                      sender                                        | last login date                 
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------
  4 | {"firstName": "Nickolai","lastName": "Nickov",       "middleName": "Nikovich", }  | 2021-04-30 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  10| {"firstName": "Vladimir","lastName": "Vladimirovich","middleName": "Putout", }    | 2021-04-17 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  11| {"firstName": "Ivan",    "lastName": "Ivanov",       "middleName": "Ivanovich", } | 2021-04-12 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  7 | {"firstName": "Petr",    "lastName": "Petrov",       "middleName": "Petrovich", } | 2021-04-10 14:49:36.234504 +00:00 
  9 | {"firstName": "Ignat",   "lastName": "Ignatov",      "middleName": "Ignatovich", }| 2021-04-06 14:49:36.234504 +00:00
```

Everything is very complicated by the fact that json is used. I had thoughts to do - "name" concatenation and perform group by and sorting, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: "Everything is very complicated by the fact that json is used." -- Yes, indeed. And that is why you should not use JSON but preferably simple columns or another table, at least for that name data as their schema seems to be fixed anyway.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: @stickybit you're right. but unfortunately in the database this data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct on()` to do this:

```
select distinct on (firstname, lastname) id, sender, last_login_date
from (
   select id, sender, last_login_date, 
          sender ->> 'firstName' as firstname,
          sender ->> 'lastName' as lastname
   from the_table
) t
order by firstname, lastname, last_login_date desc
```

Comment: thanks! but i have question. why, following the example of this request, I have an error - syntax error at or near "from"?

Comment: @IlyaY: works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=290c2acee01caf37fb6be331c6576807

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using window function :

```
select * from 
 ( 
  select * ,rank() over (partition by sender->> 'firstName',sender->> 'lastName' order by last_login_date desc) rn
  from yourtable
 ) t
where rn = 1
order by last_login_date desc
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1f6a3f48dac398a5578f2a3969466591)*

Comment: thank you friend. but I am getting the wrong result according to your example.

Comment: @IlyaY unless you gave us wrong desired output , this is producing what you showed us.see db<>fiddle in the anaswer